# Where is the history for zsh? (No `zsh_history` or `.zhistory` found)

Tags: zsh, command-history

I recently switched from `bash` to `zsh` and want to locate the file where `zsh` stores the history

In the main folder howevere, although there is a `.bash_history` There is no `zsh_history` or `.zhistory`. I also try to `locate` them without success. And if I hit the uparrow key there it appears that there is a saved history somewhere

Does somebody have an Idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The history file for the `zsh` shell is `$HISTFILE`:

```
% ls -l $HISTFILE
-rw-------  1 kk  kk  352704 May  8 14:16 /home/kk/.zsh_history
```

If this variable is unset, no history will be saved. There is no default value for this variable.

The shell has an in-memory history.  This is what you scroll through with your arrow keys. The in-memory history will obviously be lost once the shell session terminates.

A possible value to set this variable to (in your `.zshrc` file) is

```
HISTFILE=${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zsh_history
```

i.e, to `$ZDOTDIR/.zsh_history` if the variable `ZDOTDIR` is defined and not empty, or to `$HOME/.zsh_history` otherwise.  This variable does not need to be exported as it is only used by the current shell session.

The `ZDOTDIR` variable determines where the `.zshrc` and other files are picked up from (`$HOME` is used if `ZDOTDIR` is not set).

You may also want to look up `SAVEHIST` and other history-related shell variables in the `zsh` manuals.

Comment: Many thanks @Kusalananda

Comment: You also need to set the `SAVEHIST` variable to the maximum number of entries you want to save in that file (`$HISTSIZE` for the size of the in-memory history defaults to 30)

Comment: To clarify: `zsh` won't save the history if you don't set the `SAVEHIST` variable. Contrary to `HISTSIZE`, it doesn't get a default value if you don't set it.