# Set custom shell history file

Tags: zsh, configuration, command-history

How to set an alternative path for the `zsh` history file instead of the default `~/.zsh_history`?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585346/where-is-the-history-for-zsh-no-zsh-history-or-zhistory-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bsh
~/.zshrc
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
HISTFILE="your/custom/history/file/path"
```